# "mine" ambiguity

Tags: ambiguity

I have two things:

- an underground site from which resources are extracted, and
- a proximity-triggered trap device that explodes upon triggering.

Both of these are called "mine" and I cannot afford the ambiguity. So I'm looking for distinct names for them, preferably on the short side.

Comment: The former is an *excavation for extraction*. If on land, the latter is a *land mine*.

Answer (score 1):

You can just be more specific for each. A mine (first sense) is dug so that you can get something out of it, so specify what you're looking for: [***gold mine***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gold%20mine?s=t) or [***coal mine***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coal%20mine?&o=100074&s=t), for example. A mine (second sense) can be deployed either on land or sea, so you can call that a [***land mine***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/land%20mine?s=t) or [***naval mine***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/naval%20mine?&o=100074&s=t).

Comment: That won't work. A "coal mine", for example, can be both an excavation digging for coal, as well as a coal-powered explosive device. I absolutely cannot use "mine" for both.